# Node.js DGRAM module: Cannot send UDP message to remote machine but can to local machine

Tags: node.js, udp

I am running a simple UDP server using Nodejs's dgram module. 
Relevant code is simply:

```
     server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
     server.bind(10022,'127.0.0.1');
```

When I netstat on the local machine, using this:

```
 sudo netstat -l
```

I see this entry:

```
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address         State
 udp        0      0 localhost:10022     *:*
```

When I do a nmap from a remote machine using the IP address of the interface:

```
sudo nmap -sU -p 10022 192.168.7.171
```

I see this:

```
  Nmap scan report for 192.168.7.171
  Host is up (0.00032s latency).
  PORT      STATE  SERVICE
  10022/udp closed unknown
```

I have UDP client code running on the same machine which works fine when I use server.bind(10022,'127.0.0.1'), as done above. It does not when I use the real IP address assigned to the interface.

I also want to use the client code from a remote machine. So, when I use server.bind(10022, '192.168.7.171') in place of server.bind(10022,'127.0.0.1'), I would have expected to be able to send messages to the UDP process from a remote machine. I cannot. Interestingly the send function's callback, in the remote machine, does not return an error either.

How do I get the client code on the remote machine send message to the UDP server. All firewalls were shutdown for testing because I initially suspected it to be a firewall issue. In any event, both the machines are on a local intranet during testing.

Comment: The `address` is optional, if you don't specify it `bind` attempts to listen to all local addresses, does it work this way? For the error UDP is by default not reliable, once the packet is sent no acknowledgement will be sent back by the protocol.

Comment: @aghidini  Your suggestion worked! Thanks. I had read "When address and port are not passed to socket.bind() the method will bind the socket to the "all interfaces" address on a random port (it does the right thing for both udp4 and udp6 sockets). The bound address and port can be retrieved using socket.address().address and socket.address().port." in the node documentation but did not realize that you could specify the port and skip the address. **If you can post your comment as an answer, would be more than happy to accept it.**  The comment on the error in the callback makes sense too.

Comment: Happy to help, however I'm not sure why it does not work by specifying another local address like in your example, it should work also in that case.

Comment: @aghidini  I thought so too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address` parameter of `bind()` is optional, you can try to listen to all local addresses (`0.0.0.0`) by omitting it but still specify the port. Eg:

```
server.bind(10022);
```

Regarding the missing error UDP is by default a not reliable protocol, the transmission will be treated as successful when it's sent on the wire. UDP does not send back and acknowledgement packet, if you need a reliable channel you can use TCP.